# выстроить строго 3 элемента в ряд, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap

Это казалось довольно простым, но появились загвоздки..
Нужно на главной странице сделать в 3 колонки `div` с категориями, я сделал это таким способом:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В большинстве все так и стало - в 3 колонки, но если в div"е контент по содержанию больше чем в след div"ах то след div"ы будут выстраиваться друг над другом вместо того чтобы переноситься на свое место.. Примерно так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: [пример на планкр, для просмотра лучше сделать вью на полный экран](https://plnkr.co/edit/fUEyQYIIxpPX8fOoTIaj?p=preview)
Подскажите как указать что переносить не нужно?

UPD UPD: в итоге я дописал в цсс:

```
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
  }
```

насколько это будет правильно не знаю, но в решении моей проблемы это отлично помогло.

Comment: Вы вообще пытаетесь всё в 1 строку закинуть (ведь всего 1 раз класс row прописан)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  padding: 5px;
}
.col-xs-4 {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">content2<br>content<br>content<br></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content2<br>content<br>content<br><br>content<br>content<br></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Класс row подразумевает что всё остальное будет на новой строке. Приведите реальный код пожалуйста, тогда уже можно будет о чём-то говорить.